# PowerShell using CSV to remove files

Tags: powershell, csv

I am attempting to clean out voice mail files in various user directories that are over 30 days old.  I want to use a CSV to define which users to run the script against.

```cs
$csv = Import-Csv "\\Server\Name\User_Base_test.csv"

foreach ($user in $csv) {
    Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\Zultys\MX Settings\$user.vm\Voice Messages\Deleted\" -Recurse |
        Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} |
        Remove-Item
}
```

When I run this it I get the following error

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users@{USER=jdough}\AppData\Roaming\Zultys\MX Settings@{USER=jdough}.vm\Voice Messages\Deleted\' because it does not exist.
>
> At C:\Users\jasonm\Desktop\VM_SCRIPT\Clear_Old_Deleted_VM.ps1:3 char:5
>
> - Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\Zultys\MX Settings\$user.vm\Vo ...
>
> ```
>    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\@{USER...oice Messages\D:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
> ```

The CSV file has a single line in it reading jdough, one of our test users.

I have verified permissions and that the location exists.  Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: What happens when you run: foreach ($user in $csv) { "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\Zultys\MX Settings\$user.vm\Voice Messages\Deleted\" } Do the paths it generates appear ok?

Comment: What's inside `"\\Server\Name\User_Base_test.csv"` ?
Does `Get-ChildItem`part return anything?

Comment: Please show sample content from your CSV. The first couple lines should suffice. You may obfuscate sensitive information, of course.

Comment: It returns C:\Users\@{user=jdough}\AppData\Roaming\zultys\MX Settings\@{user=jdough}.vm\Voice Messages\Deleted\

The csv file has a single line in it at the moment "jdough"

Comment: @Jason - please - **_[1]_** add your CSV file to your Original Post. **_[2]_** add your FULL error message. PoSh usually has more than what you show ... and it usually is fairly useful ... [*grin*] **_[3]_** add the expanded path that your GCI call is trying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading what you are getting in the error message, I think your CSV file is a *proper* csv with headers and the field you are after is the users SamAccountName listed under header `USER`. Something like this:

```
"USER","MaybeThereIsMoreInfo"
"jdough","Nothing worth mentioning here"
"huzzle","Interesting info"
```

Changing the top line of your code to

```
$csv = Import-Csv "\\Server\Name\User_Base_test.csv" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty USER
```

will get you a `$csv` variable holding a string array of just the user SamAccountNames instead of objects with a property called `USER`.

As for the rest of the code, you would probably want to test the files for having a LastWriteTime older that 30 days (Midnight) ago, so I would advice creating a reference date above the `foreach` loop and compare to that instead of calculating this for every file over and over again:

```
# test for files older than 30 days midnight
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date

foreach ($user in $csv) {
    Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\$user\AppData\Roaming\Zultys\MX Settings\$user.vm\Voice Messages\Deleted" -File -Recurse |
        Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate)} |
        Remove-Item -WhatIf
}
```

As you can see, I've added the `-File` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to have the function only return FileInfo objects, not DirectoryInfo's.

A have also added a `-WhatIf` switch to the final `Remove-Item` so you can test first and if satisfied with the info the WhatIf shows in the console, remove that switch to actually start removing files.

Comment: That did it! I didn't realize how I was reading the csv was incorrect.  Thank you much for your assistance Theo!